# Do I boot from a Live CD now that I'm stuck on grub rescue>

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I've read all the details on how to fix getting stuck in grub, but I think I may have wiped out Ubuntu and somehow grub is still there.
I get: grub rescue> error: unknown file system
ls give me:
(hd0) (hd0,msdos8) (hd0, msdos7)....(hd0,msdos1)

I did a full restore of the Windows 7 that is on this machine (Acer 512 notebook) figuring I would just reinstall Ubuntu after, but I can't get to windows now and I don't think I have Ubuntu.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.

- choose "Try Ubuntu"
- connect internet
- open a new Terminal, then type:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

- Press Enter.
- Then type:

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (sudo boot-repair &)

- Press Enter